# How can I prevent persistent URL anchor link hash values with UI-Router?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, anchor

I'm using Angular2 and [UI-Router 2](https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/modules/ng2.html) in no-hash mode for a simple app with some anchor links in the menu. For example:

- https://example.com/blah/blech
- https://example.com/blah/blech#specifications
- https://example.com/blah/derp

If I go from a route with a hash in the URL to one without, the hash remains. For example, going from `/blah/blech#specifications` to `/blah/derp` via the menu results in a browser address of `/blah/derp#specifications`. Obviously this is incorrect and actually somewhat limiting, such as when I return to `/blah/blech` and the hash value remains, sending the window to that anchor location.

Another side effect is page refresh in a somewhat unpredictable manner. Going from `/blah/derp` to `/blah/blech#specifications` causes a full page refresh.

The setup is fairly standard:

```
export let derpState: Ng2StateDeclaration = {
    name: 'derpState',
    component: DerpComponent,
    url: '/derp'
}
```

How can I combine hash links with UI-Router 2 with good results? (Alternatively, how can I use anchor links with UI-Router in other ways?)

Answer (score 1):

which version of angular 2 you use ? Please upgrade it. No need of name and all.

```
import { ModuleWithProviders }  from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { DerpComponent }    from './derp.component';

const derp: Routes = [
{ path: 'derp',  component: DerpComponent }
];
export const derpState: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(derp);
```

Try this. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you. Latest version. Please provide some explanation of your approach here. I don't see how anchor links are handled.